# Why Session object destruction failed

Tags: php, session

I get "Session object destruction failed" when I use session_destroy().

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){    
    $_SESSION=array();
    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])){
        setcookie(session_name(),'',0,"/");
    }
    session_destroy();
}
```

What causes this error?

Comment: Why do you want to suppress the error, rather than fix it?

Comment: perhaps because of `$_SESSION=array();` or calling `session_name()` before `session_start()`? not sure which one is right...

Comment: Only the first two lines make sense, the rest of the code is baffling.  I don't think you understand how $_SESSION works.  Just call session_start() and use it.

Comment: can you post the _full_ error message?

Comment: Error: Warning: session_destroy(): Session object destruction failed - it's rather trivial, no session has been started, so you can't destroy it. The `@` operator is not always active, e.g. with error reporting functions.

Comment: Are you using a custom session handler by any chance?  Guessing no or you would have mentioned it in the question, but worth a shot.

Comment: @Corbin: Yes I was, there is no error when I disable my error handler. but I removed the "@" and still get the error (when my handler active)

Comment: Not a session error handler, but a custom session [save] handler, as registered with session_set_save_handler.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Error:

> Warning: session_destroy(): Session object destruction failed

It's rather trivial, no session <strike>has been started</strike> object has been comitted, so you can't destroy it.

The `@` operator is not always active, e.g. with error reporting functions.

**Edit:**

> 1) What causes this error?

This error is normally caused when PHP tries to delete the session file, but it can't find it.

In your case with `session_destroy` there is only [one place in PHP](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/session/session.c#115) which causes this. That's when the [`session.save_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) (see as well  [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)) returns `FALSE` for the *destroy* action. This can depends which type of save-handler you use, the default one is *files*. With that one, when the [`session.save_path`](http://php.net/session.save_path) setting is wrong (e.g. not an accessible directory), this would cause such an error.

> 2) Why would the "@" not be suppressing the error?

That depends how the output is created and on PHP configuration. `@` does not always work. For example callbacks registered with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) will still receive these messages.

Comment: There is, at least technically, a `session_start()` right at the top of the quoted code.

Comment: Maybe started, but not yet comitted, see [`session_commit`](http://php.net/session_commit).

Comment: So the answer is to `session_write_close()` before `session_destroy()`...?

Comment: No, technically not because you can't destroy a session that is not active. See [`session_destroy`](http://php.net/session_destroy). The general problem with the question is, that the `@` has been added for some reason and that reason needs to be known to tell what is going on here. Session state can be tricky in edge-cases.

Comment: "@" not needed, just an attempt to get around the problem. How can you test for an active session? I thought that the line with isset(used_id would do that.

Comment: So where do you get the error message? In STDOUT? And since when does the error occurs?

Comment: Well just remembered, `session_commit` might not unset the session id, so probably this can solve the issue. However, if `session.save_path` is wrong, this won't help either.

Comment: *"What is STDOUT?"* - STDOUT is *Standard Output*, in PHP that is what the browser displays. Are you seeing the error message in your browser or inside some log files?

Comment: Was getting error from log file, turned off my error handling routine and do not get the error anymore! What?

Comment: the error handler get's all errors, including those you try to hide away with the `@` operator - the handler callback is still invoked so (error level 0). Just don't use the `@` operator to "solve" things, use it wisely. In this case, don't use it. Instead check if your `session.save_path` configuration is correct. PHP gives you a hint about an error which you should fix, but you need to first find out what's wrong.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem when a session was created and then needs to be destroyed on the same script before it was ever created on the browser.  I don't see a solution to this problem here.

Comment: @LStarky: Please - if the code you have is not the same as here - create a new question and give the example with it of what you have there. Also report with that question which session save handler you're using. If it is the same, do not destory a session that has not yet been created. In PHP you can learn about a session state via: [`session_status()`](http://php.net/session_status)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to destroy session before cookie was created. In other words I did something like:

```
session_start();
...
session_destroy();
```

So the server didn't have a chance to 'contact' with the browser before destroying the session. 
Simple solution that worked for me was

```
session_start();
...
$_SESSION=array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using an autoloader, it may be failing to load a class that is saved in the session.