# session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed

Tags: php, session

I consulted [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2376#issuecomment-40464798) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549757/why-session-object-destruction-failed) link, but still I'm not sure what is the right workaround of this problem (which I face in my application from time to time). At least I do not understand why this seemingly most general solution

```
if(session_id() === '') session_regenerate_id($deleteOldSession);
```

should work. What looks strange is a comparison operator `===`. It seems to me, that the problem happens when there is no session file and so session_id() should be empty. So, I guess this is what we should try to avoid - to destroy session, when in fact it does not exist. So, why `===` and not:

```
if(session_id() != '') session_regenerate_id($deleteOldSession);
```

I should add that in my application `session_regenerate_id(true)` is heavily used and this procedure is invoked hundreds of times per user. But still this error pops up once or twice a day.

Comment: `===` is a [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), means that values are equal and the same type.

Comment: The triple equal sign is to check for variable type as well. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/1057527).

Comment: Thanks, for clarifying terminology, but still why `===` and not `!=` in this case ? What is the sense of using this comparison operator in the context of the problem?